# Rails http post method returning a 401 unauthorized error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

So I'm developing a simple web app, I have devise set up for user authentication.    A child of the User class is Property. Currently both registration and login work perfectly for the user. However, when I try to create a new property or edit a property I get an 401 error:

```
Started POST "/api/v1/properties" for ::1 at 2015-06-25 11:00:09 -0400
....
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

It seems as if the current_user from devise is not being passed into my properties controller so I suspect it to be a association problem or a token issue.  Any help would be appreciated.

PropertiesController:

```
class Api::V1::PropertiesController < ApplicationController

    skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => :create
    respond_to :json


    def index
        properties = Property.all
        render json: properties
    end

    def show
        respond_with Property.find(params[:id])   
    end

    def create
        property = current_user.property.build(product_params)  
        if property.save
            render json: property, status: 201, location: [:api, property] 
        else
            render json: { errors: property.errors }, status: 422
        end
    end

   ...( code below )
end
```

Property Migration:

```
class CreateProperties < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        enable_extension :postgis

    create_table :properties do |t|
        t.string :name
        t.integer :user_id 
        t.timestamps
    end

        add_index :properties, :user_id
end
```

ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_filter :authenticate_user_from_token!
    before_action :authenticate_user!

    private

    def authenticate_user_from_token!
        authenticate_with_http_token do |token, options|
        user_email = options[:email].presence
        user = user_email && User.find_by_email(user_email)

        if user && Devise.secure_compare(user.authentication_token, token)
            sign_in user, store: false
        end
    end
  end

end
```

Routes:

```
...(code above)
devise_for :users, 
path: '/api/v1/users',
controllers: { sessions: 'api/v1/sessions', :registration => "registrations" } do
  get "api/v1/users/sign_up" => "users/registrations#new", :as => :user_signup
  get "api/v1/users/sign_in" => "api/v1/sessions", :as => :user_signin
end


namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    namespace :v1 do

      resources :properties do
...(code below)
```

Comment: What is the URL you are tying to hit with? And post your routes file.

Comment: I'm running the server locally (localhost:3000) and connecting from front end at localhost:4200 .  Not sure if that answers your question.

Comment: How are you authenticating across the apps? Are you *sending* any token?

Comment: Devise generates an authentication token and 'sends' it to the front end, which is receiving the token and authenticating it because I am able to login, register and logout.